# Need suggestion for adding video conference (specially classroom / educational) in MERN stack app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have created a web app using React, Node. I want to enable video conferencing in the app and have already integrated it with Agora and also tried others.
I have also tried using core WebRTC but nothing works so perfectly.
Agora is working fine but its UI is not customizable.
Can someone please suggest me the best option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for customization would be [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/). This allows you to make an SFU and completely customize the framework to your needs. It is free and you only need to pay for your own server you deploy it on.

Here is an [EXAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms) showing simple multi-user video conferencing with audio/video/screen sharing.

Another option would be the [Janus Gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/). Haven't used it yet, but has a prebuilt backend for video/audio conferencing ready for deployment. You can then also customize the UI to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!
Will start working on Mediasoup